# VBscript to save excel sheet as pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, vbscript

I'm working on `HTML5` project.
In this project I want to create a PDF of an Excel sheet by clicking on "Make PDF" button. But my below code is not working.
Is there any way to create a PDF of an Excel sheet from HTML without opening an Excel file?

```vbs
<html><head>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub SaveExcelAsPDF ()
    'Save Excel file as a PDF

    'Initialise
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Open the file
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("file:\\\D:\\Book1.xlsx")
    objExcel.Visible = True  
    ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True  
    Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (3)  
    XlSheet.Activate  

    'Save the PDF
    objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat EXCEL_PDF, PathOfPDF(p_strFilePath), EXCEL_QualityStandard, TRUE, FALSE, , , FALSE


    'Close the file and exit the application
    objWorkbook.Close FALSE
    objExcel.Quit
End Sub
</script></head>
<body>
  <center>
    <br>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" onclick="SaveExcelAsPDF()" value="Make PDF" />
        <br> </td>
    </tr>
  </center>
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Similar VBScript for converting Excel and PowerPoint to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244131/similar-vbscript-for-converting-excel-and-powerpoint-to-pdf)

Comment: Matt Perry, I know many exceltopdf VBScript that work in excel but when I use these script in HTML, It's hopeless.

Comment: Your script works fine for me in an HTA.  Are you receiving any errors?  Make sure `PathOfPDF` returns the correct value & the excel file exists...

Comment: Yaaa, I'm receiving error- Type Mismatch 'PathOfPDF'. I don't know how to define correct value of 'PathOfPDF'

Comment: Can you provide the code for `PathOfPDF`?  Is `p_strFilePath` defined?  Realistically you can just store the path of the file in a variable, then replace the file extension with .pdf in place of your seemingly nonexistent `PathOfPDF` function call.

Comment: No "p_strFilePath" Not defined by me. May you tell me how can I do this with my script?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments (...and the code provided...), it doesn't appear you have a function `PathOfPDF(ByVal p_strFilePath)` defined which converts a file name to .pdf-

That being said... just create a few variables before you handle the file path like so:

```vbs
Sub SaveExcelAsPDF

    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    excelFilePath = "C:\File.xlsx"
    pdfFilePath = Replace(excelFilePath,".xlsx",".pdf")

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)
    objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat EXCEL_PDF, pdfFilePath, EXCEL_QualityStandard, TRUE, FALSE, , , FALSE

    objWorkbook.Close FALSE
    objExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

P.s. You don't need to display the Excel window in order for the publishing to work...  Not sure why you have code to display the excel file/window.

Comment: @iTech - if you would like me to help, please provide more details.

Comment: Where are the constants defined for vbscript?  Such as EXCEL_PDF.  I wasn't expecting that to work,  but it did.

Comment: @MrVimes - OP's `EXCEL_PDF` variable is equivalent to `vbEmpty` which would evaluate as `FALSE`, the same value as the [`xlTypePDF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195006.aspx) constant.